# Is it possible to merge two streams using CopyTo method?

Tags: merge, stream, memorystream

Is it possible to merge two (or more) Streams (or MemoryStreams) using CopyTo method?

For instance, I have two source streams s1 and s2. I'm creating the destination MemoryStream:

MemoryStream omDest = new MemoryStream();

If I copy one Stream everything is fine:

s1.CopyTo(omDest);

But if I copy both, the second one overwrites the first one.

I'd appreciate your help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the position of the target stream to the length of the first stream after CopyTo like this:

```
memoryStream1.CopyTo(target);
target.Position = memoryStream1.Length;
memoryStream2.CopyTo(target);
```

So the copying for the second stream starts at the specified position

---

**Full Code:**

```
using (MemoryStream target = new MemoryStream(30))
{
    using(MemoryStream mem1 = new MemoryStream(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }))
    {
        mem1.CopyTo(target);
        target.Position = mem1.Length;
    }
    using (MemoryStream mem2 = new MemoryStream(new byte[] { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }))
    {
        mem2.CopyTo(target);
    }
    foreach(byte b in target.ToArray())
    {
        Console.Write(b+",");
    }
}
```

Best Regards
Flo

**EDIT:**
To make it simpler you could also use the `WriteTo`-Method, so you wouldn't need the resetting of the position.

Comment: Thank you. Tried everything - CopyTo, WriteTo, specified position - only the last stream is printed. It combines everything correctly though, I can see the size of the target stream. There is something tricky about exporting to PDF, I cannot figure out what exactly.

Comment: Maybe you should adjust your question then, as this might be a problem with your PDF-stuff, maybe people are able to provide you usefull help ^^